# function trim doesn't working right php

Tags: php, trim

I have a problem with trim, it doesnt work as i expected, when the user writes only spaces in username form ("studentname") it should write you didint fill all fields ("niste izpolnili vsa polja") and i dont know how to achieve that, sorry if question is duplicate but i didnt find the answer to fix my problem
here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>vaja 5: PHP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form name='form' method='post'>
  <label class="registracija">Registracija</label>
  
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="username" class="col-sm-2">Vnesi ime</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="studentname" name="studentname">
       </div>
    </div>
         
<div class="form-group row">
      <label for="password" class="col-sm-2">Vnesi geslo</label>
      <div>
        <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1">
      </div>
    </div>
 
 <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="password" class="col-sm-2">Geslo še enkrat</label>
      <div>
        <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2">
      </div>
    </div> 
 
   <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Pritisni me" name="button">
      </div>
      </form>
</div>

<p>
<div class="container">
 <?php
if (isset($_POST["button"]))
{
echo $_POST['studentname']; 
} 
?>
<br>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["button"])) {
 $studentname = trim( $_POST['studentname'] );
 $password1 = $_POST ['password1'];
 $password2 = $_POST ['password2']; }

 
if ($_POST['studentname'] == "" || $_POST['password1'] == "" || $_POST['password2'] == "") {
        echo "Niste izpolnili vsa polja";
 } else 
if ($_POST['password1']!= $_POST['password2']) {
  echo "Gesli se ne ujemata";
 } else {
        echo "Registracija uspela";
    }
 

?>

<div>
</p>


  
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: trim -> $_POST['studentname'] == "" in your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You register a variable `$studentname` with the trim result but you actually compare to `$_POST['studentname']`. Try to use `$studentname === ""`.

Answer (score 0):

if (trim($_POST['studentname']) == "" || $_POST['password1'] == "" || $_POST['password2'] == "") {
        echo "Niste izpolnili vsa polja";

Answer (score 0):

I would enhance the following to trim all input fields, not just the `studentname`

```
if (isset($_POST["button"])) {
  $studentname = trim($_POST['studentname']);
  $password1 = trim($_POST['password1']);
  $password2 = trim($_POST['password2']);
}
```

Then make sure write your conditions on the variables, not the original POSTed values. This is the main issue in your current code.

I also rewrote your else/if to be a bit more clear.

```
// ensure that user submitted all fields
if (
  studentname == ''
  || $password1 == ''
  || $password2 == ''
) {
  echo "Niste izpolnili vsa polja";
}

// ensure that passwords match
elseif($password1 != $password2) {
  echo "Gesli se ne ujemata";
}

// validations passed
else {
  echo "Registracija uspela";
}
```

Comment: $studentname <==

Comment: glad it's working, @z.ana. if you don't mind, could you mark my answer as accepted? thanks.